# Coinbase-prime api return error: size is too accurate. Smallest unit is 0.001. For request POST /withdrawals/crypto

Tags: coinbase-api

I get error using request POST /withdrawals/crypto(https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#crypto).

"{size} is too accurate. Smallest unit is 0.001" Where size is amount when I sent in request. Looks like smallest unit depends on assets that I try to withdraw - it is different for BTC, ETH, etc.

I found info that error like this appears if use Create Order and needs to get increment from  https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#products.

But my request not about trading - only withdrawal from wallet. I try to understand what this Smallest unit means and how getting it correctly.

Comment: Did you ask their technical support?

Comment: You get the allowed precision in the error itself, so you can always just save it for that coin and refer to it again later, and retry with the given precision. In your example it seems you tried to withdraw something like 123.45678 when the smallest unit is 0.001, so you'd have to round it down to 123.456.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - yes, waiting the answer from support.
If not I'll do like you describe. 

But nevertheless  it is interesting what this means for Withdrawals